# Angular directive to change color of selected li from nested ul li elements

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-directives

I have nested `ul li` elements as below. I want to change the
`background-color` of selected `li` node when clicking on it, same time
unselected nodes `background-color` should not be changed.

```ts
<ul Parent>  
  <li Child>Child1</li>
  <li Child>Child2</li>
  <ul Parent>   
    <li Child>Child1</li>
    <li Child>Child2</li>
    <ul Parent>
      <li Child>Child1</li>
      <li Child>Child2</li>
      <li Child>Child3</li>
      <li Child>Child4</li>
      <li Child>Child5</li>
    </ul>
    <li Child>Child3</li>
    <li Child>Child4</li>
    <li Child>Child5</li>
  </ul>
  <li Child>Child3</li>
  <li Child>Child4</li>
  <li Child>Child5</li>
</ul>
```

---

```ts
import { Directive,ElementRef,HostListener,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[Parent]'
})
export class ParentDirective {

  constructor(private elem:ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('click') doOnClick(){          
    this.changeBackgroundColor("red");    
  }

  private changeBackgroundColor(color: string) {
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

I have created a parent directive to change `background-color` to white on any node is selected, and a child node directive to set `background-color` to red on node selection.

```ts
import { Directive,ElementRef,HostListener,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[Child]'
})
export class ChildDirective{

  constructor(private elem:ElementRef) {        
    this.printNativeElements(elem)    
  }

  printNativeElements(elem){
    this.liCount++;
    console.log(elem.nativeElement.parentNode.children.length);
  }

  @HostListener('click') doOnClick(){
    this.changeBackgroundColor("red");
  }

  private changeBackgroundColor(color: string) {
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

```ts
@Injectable()
class Shared {
  selected: any;
}
```

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[Parent]'
  // providers: [Shared],
})
export class ParentDirective {
  constructor(private shared:Shared) {}

  @HostListener('click') 
  clickHandler() {
    share.selected = this;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.selected')
  get isSelectedClass() {
    return shared.selected == this;
  }
}
```

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[Child]'
})
export class ChildDirective{
  constructor(private shared:Shared) {}

  @HostListener('click') 
  clickHandler() {
    share.selected = this;
  }

  @HostBinding('class.selected')
  get isSelectedClass() {
    return shared.selected == this;
  }
}
```

```ts
<ul Parent>  
  <li Child>Child1</li>
  <li Child>Child2</li>
  <ul Parent>   
    <li Child>Child1</li>
    <li Child>Child2</li>
    <ul Parent>
      <li Child>Child1</li>
      <li Child>Child2</li>
      <li Child>Child3</li>
      <li Child>Child4</li>
      <li Child>Child5</li>
    </ul>
    <li Child>Child3</li>
    <li Child>Child4</li>
    <li Child>Child5</li>
  </ul>
  <li Child>Child3</li>
  <li Child>Child4</li>
  <li Child>Child5</li>
</ul>
```

Instead of using a getter, it might be more efficient to have an observable in the shared service and the directives to subscribe to it and update an `isSelectedClass` property instead of a getter.

Comment: could u please more specific with a plnkr

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much time, but if you build a http://stackblitz.com example and run into issues, I'll have a look

Comment: It depends on if you want to have a selected item per level or only one per tree if `Shared` is provided at `ParentDirective` or a parent component of the root element.